# How to return date format from Bootstrap-vue's b-form-timepicker component from HH:mm:ss to HH:mm

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

[Bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker#comp-ref-b-form-timepicker-props) `b-form-timepicker` returns the `value` as with the format `HH:mm:ss`. I need its return value as `HH:m`', but I cannot find any way to change it.

Is there any way to change the return value format into `HH:mm`? If there is, please help.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue with my solution?

Comment: My pleasure brother!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the seconds by removing the property `show-seconds` as described in the [component table properties](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker#comp-ref-b-form-timepicker-props).  Then we'll format the date using vanilla JavaScript inside a Vue's [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) like so:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="example-input">Choose a time</label>
    <b-input-group class="mb-3">
      <b-form-input
        id="example-input"
        v-model="value"
        type="text"
        placeholder="HH:mm"
      ></b-form-input>
      <b-input-group-append>
        <b-form-timepicker
          v-model="value"
          button-only
          right
          locale="en"
          aria-controls="example-input"
        ></b-form-timepicker>
      </b-input-group-append>
    </b-input-group>
    <p>Value: '{{ value }}'</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      value: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value() {
      this.value = this.value.split(':').slice(0,2).join(':');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

You can check this [working code playground example](https://codesandbox.io/s/format-data-from-bootstrap-vue-time-picker-component-2qhlb?file=/src/App.vue).